# Access data from GraphQL in class component

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I have a code which access data from GraphQL API in an arrow function:

```
const LinkList = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(CURRENCIES);

  if (loading) return <Loader/>;
  if (error) return <pre>{error.message}</pre>

  return (
    <div className="options">
      {data.currencies.map((currency) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={currency}
            id={currency}
            className="option"
          >
            {currency.symbol}
            {currency.label}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

But I really need to implement this piece of code with access to it in a class component. I was searching a documentation with accessing data in a classes, but nothing.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@apollo/client` package and we can use `client.query` directly in the class component

```js
import {
  ApolloClient,
  gql,
  InMemoryCache,
  NormalizedCacheObject
} from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> ({
  cache: new InMemoryCache({}),
  uri: 'https://countries.trevorblades.com'
});
import * as React from 'react';

const GET_Countries = gql`
  query {
    countries{
      code
      name
    }
  }
`;

class App extends React.Component {
  getData = async () => {
    let res = await client.query({
      query: GET_Countries
    })
    console.log(res)
    // Set the state to make changes in UI
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData()
  }
  render() {
    return "Test";
  }
}

export default App;
```